# how to repeat first value of a (ordered) column grouping by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a simple table that is ordered by column ind and contains

```
create table #test (Ind int, Value int);

insert into #test (Ind, Value) values
(1, 3),
(2, 3),
(3, 3),
(4, 5),
(5, 6),
(6, 6),
(7, 3),
(8, 3);
```

Now I need a query that returns three columns: Ind, value and FirstInd. FirstInd should be the first "Ind" value within a group of "value" columns:

```
Ind Value FirstInd
1   3     1
2   3     1
3   3     1
4   5     4
5   6     5
6   6     5
7   3     7
8   3     7
```

I already tried several things and as I'm using SQL Server 2012 I could also use "lag(Ind) over (Group by Ind)" for FirstInd, but in the end I didn't find a solution yet to what first looked like a simple Problem to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ind, value, min(ind) over (partition by value, grp) as FirstInd
from (select t.*, sum(GrpStart) over (order by Ind) as Grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when lag(value) over (order by ind) = value then 0 else 1
                    end) as GrpStart
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

The idea is to find where groups of consecutive values start.  You can do this by comparing the current `value` to the previous `value` using `lag()`.  When they are different, then there is not a start.  This is a flag on one row.

Then, for any given row, sum up these flag values on the previous rows.  This produces a `grp` identifier for consecutive values.  The outer query just finds the minimum ind in that group.

Comment: I had thought about the lag() part to find the Group start but your idea to then sum this to build a Group identifier is cool.

Answer (score 1):

Please try..

```
SELECT MIN(IND) OVER(PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY Value) AS FirstInd, Ind, Value FROM #test
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Look at the last two rows.  They have a value of 3 but a different ind.

Comment: But with your query you are grouping over all values in the value column and ignore the ording in column "ind". You receive 1 for First Ind in row 7 and 8 but it should be 7.

Comment: Ahh yes I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT
    Ind,
    Value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Ind) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY Ind) AS GrpId
  FROM #test
)
SELECT
  Ind,
  Value,
  MIN(Ind) OVER(PARTITION BY GrpId, Value)
FROM t
ORDER BY Ind
```